# jest could not found haste module when test react-native component

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm using the react-native source from git for project dependency,
I put the RN source in an external directory(instead of node_modules) and add it to the extraNodeModules in rn-cli.js, so the RN packager could find all the source correctly.
but when running jest, it couldn't find any RN builtin components.

test file:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import mockCamera from '../__mocks__/camera';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
jest.mock('react-native-camera', () => mockCamera);

var TableIDInputer = props => <View />;
test('renders correctly', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<TableIDInputer />);
    let tree = component.toJSON();

    expect(tree.type).not.toBe('b');
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

test result:

> ● renders correctly
>
> ```
> Cannot find module 'View' from 'react-native-implementation.js'
>
>   146 |   },
>   147 |   get View() {
> > 148 |     return require('View');
>   149 |   },
>   150 |   get ViewPagerAndroid() {
>   151 |     return require('ViewPagerAndroid');
>
>   at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)
>   at Object.get View [as View] (../../libs/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:148:12)
>   at TableIDInputer (__tests__/test-component.js:7:31)
>   at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4137:15)
>   at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4541:16)
> ```

because the `View` component is provided by a `haste module`, which was implemented by `@providesModule` before, but today it seems it's replaced by a new mechanism, so I'm doubting is it causing the test fail??

env info:
jest: ^22.4.3
react-native:  2018-5-31 6e359c4589b0627de59332ce56fe28804425a609